# How do i ashow an active link when loading content with ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, hyperlink

i want when a user clicks on a link that loads an external ajax html file to have a visual indication that he is on that link. I want to have an active class on that but i cant since i have an animation on the links. Please help me out. Thanks 
Here is my code

**animation for my links:**

```
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop()
    .animate({"paddingLeft":"10px"}, 400) 
    .addClass('column_hover');
}, function() {
    $(this).stop()
    .animate({"paddingLeft":"0px"}, 'slow')
    .removeClass('column_hover');
});
```

**animation for the loading content:**

```
$('#loading_content').load('what-we-do/filladia.html');

$('#secondary_content_what_we_do a').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#loading_content').hide().load(url).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#secondary_content_what_we_do a').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).addClass('active').attr('href');
    $('#loading_content').hide().load(url).fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});
```

Just set a class on the current link.
Don't forget to remove the class from the previous link, if any, though.

Answer (score -1):

O......i didn't catch tour needs........

```
$('#loading_content').load('what-we-do/filladia.html',function(){
   //animation code is being here...........

   });
```

this is your needs